# Nodejs Ferros Buffer error when trying to save to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, fs

i want to use [ferros buffer](https://github.com/feross/buffer) in my application.
but i receive error when trying to save the buffer to file. here is my code : 
please kindly help to check...

```
var fs = require('fs');
var B = require('buffer/').Buffer;

 var buffin = fs.readFileSync('calibri.ttf');

 var b64 = buffin.toString('base64');

  var bf = new B(b64,'base64');

  fs.writeFile('calibro.ttf', bf, function (err) {
   if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
  });
```

here is my error message  :

```
D:\Project\testbuffer\node_modules\buffer\index.js:703
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, res)
                             ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at utf8Slice (D:\Project\testbuffer\node_modules\buffer\index.js:703:30)
    at Buffer.toString (D:\Project\testbuffer\node_modules\buffer\index.js:412:3
8)
    at fs.js:1079:63
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

please kindly help,

Comment: mmmm, probably this should go to their GitHub issues section

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you wanting to use a Buffer implementation for the *browser*, when *node* already has the original Buffer implementation? Also, you may want to check [this existing issue](https://github.com/feross/buffer/issues/69).

Comment: @mscdex the reason i want to use Buffer type for the browser is, there is a node module that i want to migrate to browser so it doesn't need nodejs. (client side only). in that function there is buffer type operation. so i will need to use the buffer implementation also for the browser. i use the fs to read and write is only to check the result.

Comment: @mscdex i will check the issue on github, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has already fixed on the latest version of feross buffer. thanks.